# Ілон Маск у кличному відмінку

Tags: відмінювання, кличний-відмінок

Як буде це імя та призвище у кличному відмінку? Ілоне Маску? Ілоне Масче?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to show any prior research.

Comment: Не розумію в чому проблема. Я написав які варіанти були в мене, і що я знайшов, але в мене є підозра, що це не правильно. Я тому і питаю, щоб дізнатися як правильно, и чому саме так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[«Правопис» 2019, § 87.1 на с. 85–96](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=95) (і те саме каже [«Правопис» 2015, § 53.1 на с. 89–90](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par53)):

> Закінчення *-у* мають <…> іншомовні імена з основою на *г*, *к*, *х* <…>: <…> *Дже́ку*, *Жа́ку*, *Лю́двігу*, *Фрі́дріху* <…>.

Отже *Ма́ску*.

*Богда́н*, *Іва́н* й інші імена на *-н* мають закінчення *-е*, і мені здається, цілком природно в ту групу вписується *І́лон*: *І́лоне*.

Отже: *І́лоне Ма́ску*.